# Beamer equivalent to \clearpage for handout notes

Tags: beamer, counters, handout

When producing notes for a `beamer` handout, I frequently have to bump the notes to a subsequent page to prevent page overflow.

I have typically done this using a `\note<handout:PN>{...}` command, where PN is a manually inserted page number which is incremented as necessary.

This is a nuisance, however; besides being very tedious to do manually, I  occasionally miss one and get jumbled notes. So I've been trying to do it using incremented counters reset by frame, but to no avail.

The example below, for example, seems to go into an infinite loop when the `\stepcounter` line is uncommented.

```
\documentclass[t,handout]{beamer}

\newcounter{notepage}[framenumber]
\newcounter{notepagei}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\newcommand\noteonpage[1]{%
    \setcounter{notepagei}{\value{notepage}}%
    \addtocounter{notepagei}{1}%
    \note<handout:\thenotepagei>{#1 (on page \thenotepagei)\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Some frame}
This is filler text.\noteonpage{First note}
%\stepcounter{notepage}%
This is more filler text.\noteonpage{Second note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If I could get this to work, it would be an improvement, but this may well be the wrong approach. In an ideal world, I'd like a) notes to overflow to another note page without my having to intervene and b) I'd also like the subsequent note pages to be produced without duplicating the original frame in between every time.